# Trying to optimize this code: iterating over a list to replace its values

Tags: python, list, optimization

I am trying to do a challenge in Python, the challenge consists of : 
Given an array X of positive integers, its elements are to be transformed by running the following operation on them as many times as required:

**if X[i] > X[j] then X[i] = X[i] - X[j]**

When no more transformations are possible, return its sum ("smallest possible sum").

Basically you pick two non-equal numbers from the array, and replace the largest of them with their subtraction. You repeat this till all numbers in array are same.

I tried a basic approach by using min and max but there is another constraint which is time. I always get timeout because my code is not optimized and takes too much time to execute. Can you please suggest some solutions to make it run faster.

```py
def solution(array):
    while len(set(array)) != 1:
        array[array.index(max(array))] = max(array) - min(array)
    return sum(array)
```

Thank you so much !

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the end result will be an array full of the GCD of the initial elements

Comment: hmm !!! that's a very interesting insight ! thank you i'll look into that !

Comment: Does the input have to be a list? You would probably get better performance using           a numpy array.

Comment: I tried to get the GCD of the whole list (using reduce and math gcd) but it also fails the test of time out, actually in that test the input is a list of length 30.000 so I need to write an optimized function that can do this task more efficiently

Comment: How are you getting the GCD? `np.gcd.reduce` is very fast for me

Comment: I used np.gcd.reduce too but it did not do it for me, here is the link for the challenge : https://www.codewars.com/kata/smallest-possible-sum/train/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I will avoid to spoil the challenge... because I didn't find the solution in Python. But here's the general design of an algorithm that works in Kotlin (in 538 ms). In Python I'm stuck at the middle of the performance tests.

Some thoughts:

- First, the idea to remove the minimum from the other elements is good: the modulo (we remove the minimum as long as it is possible) will be small.
- Second, if this minimum is `1`, the array will be soon full of `1`s and the result is `N` (the len of the array).
- Third, if all elements are equal, the result is `N` times the value of one element.

**The algorithm**

The idea is to keep two indices: `i` is the current index that cycles on `0..N` and `k` is the index of the current minimum.
At the beginning, `k = i = 0` and the minimum is `m = arr[0]`. We advance `i` until one of the following happen:

- `i == k` => we made a full cycle without updating `k`, return `N*m`;
- `arr[i] == 1` => return `N`;
- `arr[i] < m` => update `k` and `m`;
- `arr[i] > m` => compute the new value of `arr[i]` (that is `arr[i] % m` or `m` if `arr[i]` is a multiple of `m`). If thats not `m`, thats `arr[i] % m < m`: update `k` and `m`;
- `arr[i] == m` => pass.

Bascially, we use a rolling minimum and compute the modulos on the fly until all element are the same. That spares the computation of a `min` of the array periodically.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

As @BallpointBen wrote, you'll get the `n` times the GCD of all numbers. But that's cheating ;)! If you want to find a solution by hand, you can optimize your code.

While you don't find `N` identical numbers, you use the `set`, `max` (twice!), `min` and `index` functions on `array`. Those functions are pretty expensive. The number of iterations depend on the `array`.

Imagine the array is sorted in reverse order: `[22, 14, 6, 2]`. You can replace `22` by `22-14`, `14` by `14-6`, ... and get: `[8, 12, 4, 2]`. Sort again: `[12, 8, 4, 2]`, replace again: `[4, 4, 4, 2]`. Sort again, replace again (if different): `[4, 4, 2, 2]`, `[4, 2, 2, 2]`, `[2, 2, 2, 2]`. Actually, in the first pass `14` could be replaced by `14-2*6 = 2` (as in the classic GCD computation), giving the following sequence:

```
[22, 14, 6, 2]
[8, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

The convergence is fast.

```
def solution2(arr):
    N = len(arr)
    end = False
    while not end:
        arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
        end = True
        for i in range(1, N):
            while arr[i-1] > arr[i]:
                arr[i-1] -= arr[i]
                end = False
    return sum(arr)
```

A benchmark:

```
import random
import timeit

arr = [4*random.randint(1, 100000) for _ in range(100)] # GCD will be 4 or a multiple of 4

assert solution(list(arr)) == solution2(list(arr))

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: solution(list(arr)), number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: solution2(list(arr)), number=100))
```

Output:

```
2.5396839629975148
0.029025810996245127
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, and thank you for your proposed solution, however I tried it and also got a timeout, here is the challenge I am trying to solve : https://www.codewars.com/kata/smallest-possible-sum/train/python

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(a):
    N = len(a)
    end = False
    while not end:
        a = sorted(a, reverse=True)
        small = min(a)
        end = True
        for i in range(1, N):
            if a[i-1] > small:
                a[i-1] = a[i-1]%small if a[i-1]%small !=0 else small
                end = False
    return sum(a)
```

made it faster with a slight change

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I iterated on the list only once. initially I find the minimum and iterating over the list I replace the element with the rest of the division. If I find a rest equal to 1 the result will be trivially 1 multiplied by the length of the list otherwise if it is less than the minimum, i will replace the variable m with the minimum found and continue. Once the iteration is finished, the result will be the minimum for the length of the list.
Here the code:

```
def solution(a):
    L = len(a)
    if L == 1:
        return a[0]
    m=min(a)
    for i in range(L):
        if a[i] != m:
            if a[i] % m != 0:
                a[i] = a[i]%m
                if a[i]<m:
                    m=a[i]
            elif a[i] % m == 0:
                a[i] -= m * (a[i] // m - 1)
        if a[i]==1:
            return 1*L
    return m*L
```